# My Internet IP address and ISP Gateway Address in two different networks

Tags: internet, gateway, isp, wan

i was just looking at my router's status page under the Internet Settings section.

and i noticed that the Internet IP address (public ip given to me by ISP) was **197.40.227.93**

and ISP Gateway Address was **163.121.170.79**

can someone please explain how  the ***Internet IP address*** and the ***ISP Gateway Address*** be in different network.

Comment: Do you use something that is point to point, like ADSL?

Comment: Yes i use adsl.

Answer (score 1):

It looks like you use something like PPPoA or PPPoE or some other point to point protocol. Interfaces for such links don't have to be numbered, or if they are numbered they can have unrelated addresses on each end.